# How do I change the entire style of a button from code behind in realtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, triggers, background

I have a button that flashes.

I would like to change the entire button style from a resource dictionary when ever it flashes.

I would think it would be like this:

```
DesktopWindow.AlertButton.Style = (Style)DesktopWindow.Resources["GreenAlertButtonStyle"];
```

But that doesn't work. How do I do this? I cannot simply change the background color (although that's all I really want to do) because I want to preserve the triggers. When ever I change the background of the button right now, the mouseover triggers stop working....

The button:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BaseAlertButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Show Alert List"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{DynamicResource dropShadow}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AlertButtonBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" x:Name="ButtonBorder" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0"
                            BorderBrush="#ffffff" Padding="0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Image x:Name="alertImage">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/resources/alertIcon.png" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonRolloverBackground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I dont wanna hear it about doing a search for this issue....

Comment: Have you checked if DesktopWindow.Resources["GreenAlertButtonStyle"] does not return a null value?

Comment: yes, all the styles are present, and even being set with out a problem.

Comment: To be clear I want to clean out the old styles and bring in the new (after its background has been set explicitly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting background explicitly you have to clear BackgroundProperty and then set new style.

```
button1.ClearValue(BackgroundProperty);
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DesktopWindow.AlertButton.Style = FindResource("GreenAlertButtonStyle") as Style;
```

Comment: Didn't work but thank you. To be clear, I want to clean out the old styles, and bring in the new.

Comment: What happens, does the `FindResource` return anything?

Comment: Yessir, I did a quick watch on the object comming back and it is in fact the correct style. Moments before swapping the style. I do set the button background explicitly... Im not sure what that would have to do with it though. Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly use a StyleSelector (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx) instead?